# Never receive FCM notification if the phone was in energy saving mode at the time it was sent

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, power-saving

I am developing an Android app whose main use is to be notified instantly of certain events.
I have a Huawei phone.
The app works well with FCM
I receive notifications in foreground and background, from FCM console and also from my server (PHP code)

The problem is:

- I put my phone in ultra power saving mode.
- After that I send a notification. FCM return success operation.
- Finally I change my phone back to normal mode
- I Never receive the notification. Not even if I open my app.

I already check my app in "Protected Apps"

I want to know how to fix this issue. It's an Android bug? It is only a problem of this device? I mean... I do not think my code is wrong... the problem is how the OS manage FCM, google play services or whatever... there is a solution? OR an alternative cloud message service that works well? Other apps like Whatsapp doesn't have this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are a few possible reasons this is happening, however it's hard to point out which one you're experiencing without any other details other than the scenario. Could you post the related code snippets (Android side and PHP server side)?

Comment: i am having same problem